# pylint: false "Attempting to unpack a non-sequence (unpacking-non-sequence)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-typing

I have seen few threads about incorrect pylint "unpacking-non-sequence" messages, but those would have reason (like return None / return (a, b) ). But I haven't seen anything like this and i don't see the reason for pylint crying.
The code is as follows, not sure if the dataclasses can mess with things, so i am including it to be sure:

```
class FunctionDescription(Protocol):
    def get(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        ...

class SquareFunction:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x: int = x

    def get(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return self.x, self.x**2


@dataclass
class FunctionPrinter:
    function: FunctionDescription

    def run(self):
        y1, y2 = self.function() # <-- here pylint cries "unpacking-non-sequence"
        print(y1, y2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    square = SquareFunction(x=5)
    p = FunctionPrinter(function=square)
    p.run()
```

Anyone has idea why pylint complains about it? Or how I can make it "correct" ?
Thank you for you input!

**Edit:**

As Brian said: no pylint message when added `raise NotImplementedError` in `FunctionDescription.get` .

Interestingly, when `FunctionPrinter` is not a dataclass:

```
class FunctionPrinter:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function: FunctionDescription = function

    def run(self):
    # as before
```

there is no pylint message either

Comment: Able to reproduce with pylint 2.14.4. The issue seems to be with pylint's understanding of protocols (specifically that it shouldn't try to analyze their lack of return statements). The lint goes away if you add `raise NotImplementedError` to `FunctionDescription.__call__` or change the typehint of `FunctionPrinter.function` to `SquareFunction`. Neither the dataclass or the fact that you're using `__call__` seem to matter, so I would recommend removing them from this [mre].

Comment: Thank you Brian. I tried to modify it as you said. Interesting that `FunctionPrinter` is /is not a dataclass has impact on this pylint message..